# Start a docker machine using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, docker, docker-machine

I'm actually facing a problem to start my machine by my JavaScript. I can stop the running machines without any problems but I can't start.

The error is the next one :

```
/Users/swisscom_NG/Desktop/mgmt-docker-gui/node_modules/docker-machine/index.js:79
W20170106-13:19:51.164(1)? (STDERR)         done()
W20170106-13:19:51.164(1)? (STDERR)         ^
W20170106-13:19:51.165(1)? (STDERR)
W20170106-13:19:51.165(1)? (STDERR) TypeError: done is not a function
```

The code executed is :

```
'machine.start': function(name){
  Machine.start(name);
}
```

And Machine is defined like this:

```
import Machine from 'docker-machine';
```

The error is because it thinks that the machine is running but if I look into Docker I can see :
[image]

I'm using [node-docker-machine](https://github.com/vweevers/node-docker-machine)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the documentation of docker-machine you need to pass a done function to get the callback when docker-machine finish the start event. so just change your code as this:

```
Machine.start(name, function(){ console.log('Docker Started') });
```